# How to transcode six digits emoji code to Unicode by Javascript? (`328054` to `\ue052`)

Tags: javascript, unicode, emoji

There are some texts contain six digits emojis. I need transcode it to Unicode by JavaScript.

Just like this:

```
origin:  328054 


Unicode:  \ue052    ( U+E052  'the dog face' Emoji )
```

How can I transcode this six digits emoji code to Unicode by Javascript?

Comment: How are those two things supposed to be related? Also, `U+E052` is unassigned.

Comment: @一二三: It belongs to Private Use Area, so anyone can map anything there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> origin:  328054

I have no idea what you mean. If treated decimal, [U+50176](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/50176/index.htm) is not a valid Unicode character. If treated hexadecimal, it lies outside the range of code points Unicode can represent.

> Unicode:  \ue052    ( U+E052 )

[U+E052](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e052/index.htm) is reserved for private use. You don't mean that one. It seems to have been used by [SoftBank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SoftBank) to encode the *Dog Face* emoji. Unless you live in Japan, and use their network, it hardly will work for you.

> 'the dog face' Emoji

is assigned [U+1F436](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f436/index.htm): .

> How can I encode this in Javascript?

JavaScript uses [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16), and since your code point is higher than U+D7FF, you will need two characters to encode it as a surrogate pair. You still can easily get the string from the code point by using [`String.fromCodePoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint):

```
var df = String.fromCodePoint(0x1F436);
df.length; // 2
```

You can get the character codes that you need for escaping from that string using the [`charCodeAt` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt):

```
String.fromCodePoint(0x1F436).charCodeAt(0).toString(16) // d83d
String.fromCodePoint(0x1F436).charCodeAt(1).toString(16) // dc36
```

So the JS string literal you seem to be after is `"\ud83d\udc36"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what I need to find. Maybe my origin data has wrong. (328054-200000).toString(16) == 1f436. But I can't find the person who leave these data in our Servers! Thanks again, now I can handle this.